# update cakephp3 with composer leads to missing dependencies

Tags: cakephp, composer-php

i want to update my cakephp 3.5 to 3.6 and i used composer

```
composer require --update-with-dependencies "cakephp/cakephp:3.6"
```

but e.g. dependency 'dotenv' is missing (it is not contained in my current local installation). dotenv has also no entry in composer. Do i have to update an composer.json manually?

Comment: "i want to update ..." THEN ```composer update --update-with-dependencies "cakephp/cakephp:3.6"```

Comment: thanks @salines. i used 'require' because cakephp documentation says it. using 'update' still does not include dotenv. cakephp installation from scratch does include it.

Comment: i deleted Composer.lock and made an update. still the same Problem: if the newer cakephp release has some additional (third party) dependencies (e.g. dotenv) these dependencies are not updated in the composer.json.  Is this a bug or is it a feature? So, if i edit composer.json manually how do i know which version of the new dependency is needed?